# string array randomization ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (EDITED)

Tags: android, arrays, string, indexoutofboundsexception

### Need help guys. I added random method in my code and now i'm getting this error.

---

```
12-17 11:03:38.921: E/AndroidRuntime(306): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 11:03:38.921: E/AndroidRuntime(306): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
12-17 11:03:38.921: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at com.example.boardrace.MainActivity.isCorrect(MainActivity.java:97)
12-17 11:03:38.921: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at com.example.boardrace.MainActivity.checkAnswer(MainActivity.java:107)
12-17 11:03:38.921: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at com.example.boardrace.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
12-17 11:03:38.921: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-17 11:03:38.921: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-17 11:03:38.921: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-17 11:03:38.921: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-17 11:03:38.921: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-17 11:03:38.921: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-17 11:03:38.921: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 11:03:38.921: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-17 11:03:38.921: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-17 11:03:38.921: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-17 11:03:38.921: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

### here's the whole code I saw in youtube

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int currentQuestion;
private String [] questions;
private String [] answers;
private Button answerButton;
private Button questionButton;
private TextView questionView;
private TextView answerView;
private EditText answerText; 

Random random = new Random();
String randString = questions[random.nextInt(questions.length)];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
}

public void init()
{questions = new String[]{"Q1?","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q5","Q6","Q7","Q8","Q9","Q10"};
 answers = new String[]{"A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","10",};
 currentQuestion = -1;
 answerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AnswerButton);
 questionButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.QuestionButton);
 questionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.QuestionTextView);
 answerView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerTextView);
 answerText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AnswerText);

 answerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {checkAnswer();              }});

 questionButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 showQuestion();
     }});
}

public void showQuestion()
{ currentQuestion++;
 if(currentQuestion == questions.length)
 currentQuestion =0;
questionView.setText(questions[currentQuestion]);
 answerView.setText("");
 answerText.setText("");
}

public boolean isCorrect(String answer)
{return (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[currentQuestion]));
}

public void checkAnswer()
{String answer = answerText.getText().toString();
 if(isCorrect(answer))
 answerView.setText("You're right!");
 else answerView.setText("Sorry, the correct answer is "+answers[currentQuestion]);
}
}
```

the code is about randomization of questions and you will type the correct answers.

Comment: What is line 97 in MainActivity.java?

Comment: In your String randString = questions[random.nextInt(questions.length)]; line random.nextInt(questions.length) is producing a number larger than the size of the array - 1. Fix that and there wont be that error.

Comment: post the `isCorrect` method code

Comment: What about the fact that this String randString = questions[random.nextInt(questions.length)]; is being declared before questions is declared in init(). Is that ok?

Comment: Please post the `isCorrect` method. That is the one throwing exception. Also don't post it in the comment, `edit` and update your question. Thanks!

Comment: @JoelFernandes line 97 is a closing semicolon.

Comment: You are not even using `String randString = questions[random.nextInt(questions.length)];` why have it?

Comment: @AmulyaKhare but how should I random my code without it? I got the code somewhere in stackoverflow though and just reapplying it. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String randString = questions[random.nextInt(questions.length)];`

Since `randString` is declared as a member variable, So this is assigned value when object of class is created, this assignment is dependent on `questions`, which is initialized in `init()`, this `init()` would be called after object creation. That is why you are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`, because you try to access `questions` before it was initialized.

Flow:

1. Object is created.
2. Members are initialized.

   2.a) `randString` is assigned value, but this require `question`.

   2.b)  So now, `question` is looked up.

   2.c)  Only declaration of `question` can be found. `question` is not referring to any value.

   2.d)  Now `questions[random.nextInt(questions.length)]` is trying to access value at some index ( random int ), but `question` does not have anything till now.

   `This is point where exception is raised.`

`Solution`

If `randString` is some initialization parameter then do

```
init(){
// some code
questions = new String[]{"Q1?","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q5","Q6","Q7","Q8","Q9","Q10"};
String randString = questions[random.nextInt(questions.length)];
// some code
}
```

Comment: it solves arrayindexoutofboundsexception, thank you. and now randString become "not used" and have yellow wiggly underline and the question is not randomized. thank you for your answer sir @GauravGupta

Comment: can you help me how to random it?

Comment: @Jan please describe the problem in detail, or come over chat to detail discussion

Comment: well the problem is I need the questions to be generated randomly, and at the same time it can check the correct answer to it. where can we chat?

Comment: This is logical problem which i think you yourself try, though i can give you some idea. 1. `randString` contains which question number you want to generate ( e.g "Q1" or "Q2" ). 2. Now, you should have some set of question and answers stored ( either database or in some other data-structure (map/list/set)). 3. you need to find `randString` refers to which question in your collection of question . Now when you find the question, then this question should be mapped with correct answer from the question.

Comment: How do I manipulate randString? I'm having a hard time with it and I'm avoiding the use of database because i think it is more complicated than arrays, besides i'm not good at it. do you have any links related to this?

Comment: I think you should first read about few topics. "collection", "String", "class". http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm , http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
questions[random.nextInt(questions.length-1)];
```

The idea is array position start from 0 . so your quesrion array has value in between 0 to 9 position.

You are passing total length that is 10 and it is beyond last position and that is 9.

Comment: `nextInt(max)` returns a number from `0` and `max-1` both inclusive.. `length-1` will be wrong as it will return in range `0-8`

Comment: no @AmulyaKhare . it will return 10 as total length. so 10 - 1 = 9

Comment: `questions.length = 10` => `questions.length-1 = 9` => `nextInt(questions.length-1) = nextInt(9)` => output is from `0-8` read documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)

Comment: I will try this guys. I will just solve this nullpointerexception a new error when I made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the comma "," at the end of answers array

```
answers = new String[]{"A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","10",};
```

as

```
answers = new String[]{"A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","10"};
```

Comment: thank you, but it didn't solve the problem. sorry. I just update my code and now I'm getting nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you init `currentQuestion = -1;`. So if for the first time, you click on the answer button **without clicking on the question button before it**, it will execute:

```
public boolean isCorrect(String answer) {
     return (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[-1]));
}
```

Hence the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.